# CRM 2011 sdk - quickest/most efficient way to get contact info + associated list IDs

Tags: vb.net, linq, dynamics-crm-2011

Our CRM 2011 database contains approx. 20000 contacts, and I need to loop through all of them using the SDK. Currently I'm finding the following linq query takes a very long time to execute:

```vb
Dim contactList = From c In orgService.ContactSet 
  Select New With {
    Key .ContactId = c.ContactId,
    Key .EMailAddress1 = c.EMailAddress1,
    Key .ListIds = From l In c.listcontact_association Select l.ListId
  }
```

As you can see, I just need a couple of fields from each Contact, and a list of associated Marketing List IDs. Perhaps it's taking a long time because it's doing an additional query (to get the list IDs) within each contact result?

I'm fairly new to Linq, so not sure how the above translates to actual FetchXML communication. Is there a more efficient way of getting that info which would result in shorter query run time?

**More Info:** I'm writing code to sync a CRM database with a CreateSend database. So I do need to go through *all* contact records, not only adding to the CS database, but also reflecting changes in list membership and updating activity or other info for each contact where needed. The sync process will eventually run nightly on the CRM server itself, so it's expected to take time to run, but of course I want to make it as efficient as possible.

Comment: What is taking a long time - the query to get all the contacts, or iterating through all 20,000 of them?

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of more information, it looks like your query is actually two - one query to get the list of contacts, and then another to get the list of list ids. This means SQL Server is returning the full list of 20,000 contacts, then *for each* contact, your code asks SQL Server for the list of associated list ids.

This means you are making ***20,000 + 1*** separate calls to SQL Server (though this is actually an abstracted total - the CRM SQL translator actually makes more than that, but it doesn't add significant overhead).

So what you really want to do is make just **1** query that gets you *all* your data, and *then* begin to work with it. I'm not proficient enough in VB.NET to make the translation, but the below C# code should get you there most of the way.

```cs
// Gets all contacts and list ids in a flat result set
var contacts = from c in orgService.ContactSet
               join lms in orgService.ListMemberSet on c.ContactId equals lms.EntityId.Id into leftJoinedContact
               from ljc in leftJoinedContact.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where ljc.EntityType == Xrm.Contact.EntityLogicalName
               select new
               {
                   c.ContactId,
                   c.EMailAddress1,
                   ljc.ListId
               };

// Calls .ToList() to put the result set in memory
var contactList = contacts.ToList();

// Manipulates the result set in memory, grouping by contact info
var newContactList = contactList.GroupBy(x => new {x.ContactId, x.EMailAddress1})
    .Select(x => new {x.Key.ContactId, x.Key.EMailAddress1, Ids = x.Select(y => y.ListId).ToList()})
    .ToList();

// var contactsWithListIds = newContactList.Where(x => x.Ids.Where(y => y != null).Any()).ToList();
// var contactsWithoutListIds = newContactList.Where(x => x.Ids.Where(y => y != null).Any()).ToList();

foreach (var contact in newContactList)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

But we need more information.  The fastest way is to use straight SQL (i.e. filtered views).

The second fastest way is to use straight FetchXML (although some may debate that linq is on par with this in terms of performance).

If you can filter your query to reduce the 20,000 records to only the records you need, you'll save the most time however.  So the first question I have is why are you iterating through the 20,000 records?  Do you need to process them all or do you need to check them all for certain criteria and then do something based on if they match the criteria?

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping out. I've updated the description with more info. It's a sync operation so I do need to go thu all records.

Comment: Paul, you're *that* close to my -1. What evidence do you have to support your claim that straight SQL is fastest, and filtered views at that? And then you say straight FetchXml is faster, and then mention Linq. There can be no debate about which is faster in the absence of solid testing here.

Comment: But I do want to give a +1 for the part about pre-filtering. So conflicted.

Comment: @PeterMajeed - Am I wrong in assuming that nothing beats going straight to the database tables themselves (with the knowledge that you loose all role based security and enter yourself up to possibly having issues with Microsoft performing a breaking change).

Paul - Since Linq gets converted into Query Expressions they will run marginally (for most queries, we're talking like milliseconds) faster than LINQ since the SDK doesn't have to do any translation work.

Comment: @Daryl: For a whole bunch of stuff, definitely, and that's mostly because of the restrictions that the CRM API places on *query logic*. But given a straight `SELECT * FROM ___ (INNER JOIN ___ WHERE ___ ORDER BY ___ etc.)`, I don't know of any significant *speed* advantage that native SQL queries have over dealing with FetchXml/Linq/QueryExpressions.

Comment: @PeterMajeed We're talking general terms so I'll settle with your 0 score :)  In this case, whichever way is chosen is relatively moot.  The time is going to be spent iterating through the records individually (based on the feedback thus far).

Comment: @Daryl agreed on the milliseconds and just wanted to avoid that debate that Peter has violently thrust us into now (total sarcasm)